# I cant find what is missing in one of the methods

Tags: java, methods

```
public class Main {
    private static void printStars(int amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    private static void printWhitespaces(int size2) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    private static void printTriangle(int size) {
        for (int i=1; i<=size; i++) {
            {
                for (int j=size-i; j>=1; j--)
                    printWhitespaces(size);
            }
            for(int k=1; k<=size; k++) {
                printStars(size);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(7);
    }
}
```

The problem is in here `for(int k=1; k<=size; k++){printStars(size);}`
this function doesn't want to print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 stars on each pass instead every time it prints the total amount of the stars in each line, currently 7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I indented your code. I see you have an extra opening brace inside `printTriangle`. You may want to move that into the `for` loop it surrounds. It will have no effect on your output though.

Comment: I tried removing brackets there, nothing changes

Comment: What is the `int` parameter to `printStars` and `printWhitespaces` intended to do? They are currently unused. Did you intend to put a loop there?

Comment: I can'te delete those int's, the methods will stop working if i do, the idea was, those int's to take the values from the size int

Comment: Why would it stop working? You aren't using them, so you can remove them from the code if you aren't going to use them. Otherwise, you need to write code that uses them.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A triangle, that starts with 1 * and +1 * on each line on the right side

Comment: Does [this Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/a4OkY7) have the correct output?

Comment: It should the aligned on the right side, first the spaces then the stars

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what way you choose to achieve the triangle "as a tip: to work with console you may use `\\n`" ; The code conception may be like this see code snippet

**TESTED**

```
 public class Main{
    private void printStar() {
              System.out.print("*");
           }
           private void printLineBreak() {
               System.out.println();
           }
           private void printWhitespace() {
               System.out.print(" ");
           }
           private void printWhitespaces(int size) {
               for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                   System.out.print("~");//replace with something else
                   this.printWhitespace();
               }
           }

       private void printLeftToRightTriangle(int size) {
           for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
               for(int j=0; j<i+1; j++){               
               printStar();
               printWhitespace();
       }    
               this.printWhitespaces(size-(i+1));
               this.printLineBreak();

       }
       }

       private void printRightToLeftTriangle(int size) {
           for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
               this.printWhitespaces(size-(i+1));   
               for(int j=0; j<i+1; j++){                                   
                   this.printStar();
                   this.printWhitespace();
       } printLineBreak();

       }
       }

       public Main(){
           this.printLeftToRightTriangle(7);
           this.printRightToLeftTriangle(7);
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
               new Main();
           }
}
```

**EDIT**
@Jone I edited my code; I am not sure why you use whitespaces; You say about right triangle so I tried to create left to right and right to left triangle (see my console output);

```
* ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
* * ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
* * * ~ ~ ~ ~ 
* * * * ~ ~ ~ 
* * * * * ~ ~ 
* * * * * * ~ 
* * * * * * * 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ * 
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ * * 
~ ~ ~ ~ * * * 
~ ~ ~ * * * * 
~ ~ * * * * * 
~ * * * * * * 
* * * * * * *
```

If you need additional information please let me know.

I hope this helps a bit :)

Comment: No, if a newline is desired they would use `System.out.println()`

Comment: Original question contains `print` only; If it is interesting to use `print` he may  use `\\n`  as I describe

Comment: They used `println` in their code, but also I'm pretty sure they don't want that many newlines.

Comment: No, the original question contains `print` all the time; Maybe that's important! So I advise to use `\\n` in this case

Comment: The last line of the outer loop is `System.out.println("");` Plus, using `\\n` will print a literal `\n` to the output. You have one-to-many backslashes. Also, `\n` is not a cross-platform line terminator, which means `println` is the better choice for that job.

Comment: You are confusing regex escape sequences with string escape sequences. Try running your code on https://ideone.com/

Comment: @Jone I edited the code and tested it (tested on Linux); But I am not sure about you triangle task :S Give more details

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,j
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 

        for (i = y; i < size - 1; i++)

            System.out.print(' ');

        for (j = 0; j < y * 2 + 1; j++)
             System.out.print('*');

        System.out.println();
    }
```

hope it help !!

Comment: It created a triangle but it's upside down, it starts with 7 stars and ends with 1 i am trying to do it the opposite way

Comment: Ok with your tip I managed to get it to work correctly 'for(int k=i; k>=1; k--)' this is the working line, but I still dont understand why my original approach wasnt working which was like this "for(int k=1; k<=size; k++)" if anyone can explain

Comment: cause the number of whitespaces decrease every line when you use from 1 to size its a constant value every time you will get the same number of whitespaces .

Comment: Code only answers are greatly discouraged on SO, as they don't provide any explanation for the solution to the problem. Please edit your answer to describe how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need the number of spaces to decrease with each line, while the number of stars to increase with each line. So at each line, the number of spaces will be `size - i`, and the number of stars will be `i`. With your code, it was always printing `size` number of stars, instead of `i` number of stars.

To fix your code, change `k<=size` to `k<=i`.

Here is a working version of your code, with your methods modified for readability.

```
public class Main {
    private static void printNTimes(char c, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    private static void printTriangle(int size) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            printNTimes(' ', size - i);
            printNTimes('*', i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(7);
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/a4OkY7)